# Change keyboard backlight on or off

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard, backlight

Location of the cfg files for this are in `/sys/class/leds`. Here I have a few Input values, when I try to edit capslock, all I have to do is set `/sys/class/leds/input3::capslock/brightness` with 0/1, and the led works. But I can't find the file the kbd-backlight. I'm on Linux Mint 18.

Comment: There is no such thing, backlighting is a proprietary extension.  Some keyboards do have Linux utilities for changing backlighting, others don't.  It's in no way standardised, each vendor does it a different way.